# Javascript: not modifying global variables in slider function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider on my webpage and I am attempting to manipulate this timings based on the current slide using a global variable. My question is: am I correctly manipulating the global variable (setting it to 10000 or 2000) and/or am creating the global variable in the correct place.

Thanks always,
Rock

```
<script>
    var timer = 4000;
    function slideShow() {
        var displayToggled = false;
        var current1 = $('.slide:visible');
        var nextSlide = current1.next('.slide');
        var hideoptions = {
            "direction": "left",
            "mode": "hide"
        };
        var showoptions = {
            "direction": "right",
            "mode": "show"
        };


        if (current1.is(':last-child')) {
            current1.effect("slide", hideoptions, 2000);
            $("#firstSlide").effect("slide", showoptions, 2000);
            timer = 10000;
        }
        else if (current1.is(':first-child')) {
            current1.effect("slide", hideoptions, 1000);
            nextSlide.effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
            timer = 2000;
        }
        else {
            current1.effect("slide", hideoptions, 2000);
            nextSlide.effect("slide", showoptions, 2000);
            timer = 10000;
        }
    };

    setInterval(slideShow, timer);
    slideShow();
</script>
```

references:
The original slide show: [Simple Slideshow jQuery/UI images inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871182/simple-slideshow-jquery-ui-images-inline)

live-site example: http://www.nerdherdgames.com

**Edit:** The live site does not currently have this particular javascript on the index page

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can give you a live site example: http://www.nerdherdgames.com

Comment: What is your problem ? Your variable `var timer = 4000;` is set at the right place if it is what you want to know.

Comment: @daguru I am trying to change the value of the variable timer based on the current slide inside the function slideshow() i.e. `timer = 10000` or `timer = 2000` within each of the if, else-if, and else blocks. Thanks, and I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval(slideShow, timer);` will be set just once, so the interval will be the first value in `timer` alternatively you can use a `setTimeout` so you will set the timer every time the function ends. That means, instead of changing `timer`s value on each slide you should start a `setTimeout` at the end of the animation.

[setTimeout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference and appropriate differences between setInterval and setTimeout for me.

Answer (score 0):

Number is primitive type in javascript, it's not a object, object is passed by reference, but number is passed by value. So after the first time you invoke

```
setInterval(slideShow, timer);
```

No matter how you change the variable timer, it won't affect the interval set at the first time.